# View remote shapeFile with ArcGis API for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, shapefile, arcgis-js-api

I implemented the following sample code in order to display zipped shapeFiles on a ArcGis map and it works when I select the desired shapeFile manually: 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html

In my application I have the url to the .zip File that is saved on a local server. According to the sample code I need to send a request (rest generate operation) to the arcGis server in order to receive the needed featureCollections. In the sample code the parameter 
form: dom.byId('uploadForm') specifies the form tag where the .zip file is saved.

After some research I have found that the request can also have a "file" parameter ( http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r300000083000000 ), but I don't know how I can view a zip file without downloding and saving it on my local computer. Is there a way to download the file, save it in a variable and send it this way to the server?

Best regards, 
Lea A.